# Doctrine 1.2 + float value not accepted. Only integer seems to work

Tags: types, doctrine

Here is a snippet from the base class:

```
$this->hasColumn('order_total', 'float', null, array(
         'type' => 'float',
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
```

And here is my usage:

```
public function preInsert($event)
{    
    echo $total = $this->_totalWithTax;

    $this->order_total = $total;

    $this->created_at = Zend_Date::now()->toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
}
```

For some reason, it only works if `$total` is an integer, but does not work when it's value is a float (which by the way, is the most common scenario). I tested this by type-casting.

I'm at the point of tearing my hairs out in my vain attempts to comprehend why it is so.

Also, using `$this->_set('order_total', $total);` doesn't work either.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I have a getter override within the class:

```
public function getOrderTotal()
{
    return $this->_totalWithTax;
}
```

In case it does make a big difference.

When calling the `save` method, I get this error:

```
Validation failed in class LP_Orders 1 field had validation error: * 1 validator failed on order_total (notnull)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with this:

```
$this->hasColumn('order_total', 'float', null, array(
         'type' => 'float',
         'scale' => 8,
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
```

Comment: Tried it. Unfortunately, doesn't fix it.

Comment: Then you should try with decimal I think, but maybe you should up scale value.

Comment: I've set it to decimal as you suggested, but it didn't fix it either.

BTW I edited the question with additional information that might matter.

(Thanks both for your time.)

Comment: Can you give order_total field type on sql? Are you sure that it is double? And could you please write Doctrine exception?

Comment: Updated the question with the exception. `order_total` is float in the database.

Comment: I am suggesting that you may use decimal at sql and double at doctrine.